# error CS1503: Argumento 2: não é possível converter de "string" para "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ServerVersion"

Tags: c#, entity-framework

ME ajudem rapaziada, ja tentei de tudo e o erro nao sai de jeito nenhum!!!

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using projeto_POO_seige.Data;

namespace projeto_POO_seige
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddDbContext<SeigeProjetoContext>(options => 
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SeigeProjetoContext"), 
            builder => builder.MigrationsAssembly("Projeto_POO_Seige")));

            services.AddMvc();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

O erro parece ser bem claro, você está passando uma string ao invés de um objeto do tipo ServerVersion.
Veja os parametros que o metodo UseMySql espera.

```
string connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("SeigeProjetoContext");


x.UseMySql(connectionString , ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString)
```